# How do you write Angular tests for ag-Grid when using fakeAsync zone?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, testing, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

When testing ag-Grid in Angular applications using the fakeAsync zone, I receive the error `Error: 4 timer(s) still in the queue`.

I do not get this error if I just render my data to the screen without using ag-Grid and my tests pass.

Note that this is only an issue when testing with fakeAsync and if I test synchronously then tests with ag grid work as expected.

A full reproduction can be found on [Github](https://github.com/cjcoops/test-ag-grid-repro) or [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/cjcoops/test-ag-grid-repro). The project has an example with ag grid which fails and the same example without ag grid which passes.

In the example I have a search control on which I listen for value changes, debounce 300ms, and then fetch some data before populating the grid with the response data.

```
class WithAgGridComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataService: DataService) {}

  searchControl = new FormControl('');

  columnDefs = [
    { headerName: 'ID', field: 'id' },
    { headerName: 'Title', field: 'title' }
  ];

  rowData;

  modules = AllCommunityModules;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(300),
        switchMap(value => this.dataService.fetch())
      )
      .subscribe(posts => (this.rowData = posts));
  }
}
```

My tests are as follows (using Spectator for readability). I mock the data request by waiting 100ms before returning the data.

```
describe('WithAgGridComponent', () => {
  let spectator: Spectator<WithAgGridComponent>;
  const createComponent = createComponentFactory({
    component: WithAgGridComponent,
    imports: [
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      AgGridModule.withComponents([])
    ],
    mocks: [DataService],
    detectChanges: false
  });

  it('should display the posts', fakeAsync(() => {
    spectator = createComponent();
    const dataService = spectator.get(DataService);
    dataService.fetch.andCallFake(() =>
      timer(100).pipe(mapTo([{ id: 1, title: 'testing ag grid' }]))
    );
    spectator.detectChanges();

    spectator.typeInElement('Test', 'input');

    tick(300);
    spectator.detectChanges();

    expect(spectator.query(byText('testing ag grid'))).not.toExist();

    tick(100);
    spectator.detectChanges();

    expect(dataService.fetch).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(spectator.query(byText('testing ag grid'))).toExist();
  }));
});
```

Comment: Try to increase tick value to 1000 or 2000, or even more as needed, you have to add a tick immediately after a `detectChanges` because template needs to be updated, or, for  any event to have time to be addressed. try https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flushMicrotasks as well

Comment: @HDJEMAI thanks adding tick(1000) after the last detectChanges did the trick!